# How can i change only one boolean value when other two remains false and make them turn each other with this rule? C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, boolean

Hi my question is in the header, i really tried to find how to do this but couldn't find any solution yet, im a newbie so i really need your help guys.

bool a;
bool b;
bool c;

Simply :  a,b,c are false : make one true then make false again when others remains false, and make one true again.

There are 3 options: A - B - C, and i want to do 3 things with if statements,

if(a) ....

if(b)....

if(c) ....

so, everytime i need to choose(randomly) only one of them (a or b or c),

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. How to assign a value to a variable, like `a = true;`? And which for loop are you referring to in the tags?

Comment: You have to give us more details. Your question is completly unclear for me.

Comment: Okay, now here is the situation;  There are 3  options: A - B - C, and i want to do 3 things with if statements, if(a) .... if(b).... if(c) ....  //// so while i do this there must be only one bool should be true and i want to do this randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the recent comments, it sounds like what you're *actually* trying to do is choose randomly between three options. Forget about bools; what you need is simply:

```
var rand = new Random(); // ideally keep this between uses - maybe a field
//...
switch (rand.Next(3)) // means 0-2
{
    case 0: // a
        //...
        break;
    case 1: // b
        //...
        break;
    case 2: // c
        //...
        break;
}
```

Comment: AAAA amazing help bro!! wish you have best day !!!! happy new year thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you're asking. I would start by describing the state's you want to represent. If it is "none, a-only, b-only, c-only", then I wouldn't bother with the bools - I'd just use a counter from 0-3, and work from there. You *could* also use a `[Flags] enum` with the values `0`, `0b001`, `0b010` and `0b100` but IMO that is over-complicating things. Another option (if that is unclear) could be an array of tuples of the states you want, for example

```
new[] {(false,false,true),(false,true,false),(true,false,false)}
```

This could also be done by using the loop counter as a "left-shift" operand from the literal `1`, and using binary arithmetic.

If the states are "all combinations of on/off pairs over 3 bools", then that's just binary integer arithmetic - you'd do a loop from 0-7 and look at the bitwise components of the loop iterator.

If none of this makes sense: maybe try clarifying the question so we can see exactly what you're trying to do - then we can respond with code.

Comment: wow bro, if i say i understand would've lyed to you :D:DD  im going to take a book :D